# Compare two lists (one of them with another list) and return the index of the matches

Tags: python-2.7

```
a = ['french', 'english']

b = ['(portuguese; french)', '(english)']
```

I want to compare two lists and in return I want the index of the matches

I tried:

```
matches = list([i for i, item in enumerate(a) if item in b]+[i for i, item in enumerate(b) if item in a])
```

But the result was an empty list

Comment: Example output?

Answer (score 0):

do you need this..

```
b = ['(portuguese, french)', '(english)']
a = ['french', 'english']
matching = [i for i, x in enumerate(b) if any(thing in x for thing in a)]
print matching


output: [0, 1]
```